# Excel Macro, Combining two Private Sub worksheet_change

Tags: excel, vba

I search before in this site, but not really found same case with my code. Hope someone here can help me on this.
How to combine two Private sub below?

> 1st code

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Range("P:P")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Target = "" Then Exit Sub
Dim NR As Long
With Application
  .EnableEvents = False
  .ScreenUpdating = False
  Select Case Target.Value
    Case "CLOSED"
      NR = Worksheets("Closed").Range("D1500").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
      Range("B" & Target.Row & ":P" & Target.Row).Copy Worksheets("Closed").Range("B" & NR)
      Rows(Target.Row).Delete
    Case "Re-handover"
      NR = Worksheets("Handover").Range("D1500").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
      Range("E" & Target.Row & ":O" & Target.Row).Copy Worksheets("Handover").Range("E" & NR)
      ' Rows(Target.Row).Delete
      End Select
  .EnableEvents = True
  .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub
```

> 2nd code

```
Option Explicit
Public preValue As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Column <> 15 Then Exit Sub
    Target.ClearComments
Target.AddComment.Text Text:="Updated " & Format(Date, "dd mmm yyyy") & " " & Format(Time, "hh:mm") & Chr(10) & "By " & Environ("UserName")
End Sub
```

thank you very much before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work?

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

*If target.column=15 then
    Target.ClearComments
    Target.AddComment.Text Text:="Updated " & Format(Date, "dd mmm yyyy") & " " & Format(Time, "hh:mm") & Chr(10) & "By " & Environ("UserName")
else
endif *


If Intersect(Target, Range("P:P")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If Target = "" Then Exit Sub
Dim NR As Long
With Application
  .EnableEvents = False
  .ScreenUpdating = False
  Select Case Target.Value
    Case "CLOSED"
      NR = Worksheets("Closed").Range("D1500").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
      Range("B" & Target.Row & ":P" & Target.Row).Copy Worksheets("Closed").Range("B" & NR)
      Rows(Target.Row).Delete
    Case "Re-handover"
      NR = Worksheets("Handover").Range("D1500").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
      Range("E" & Target.Row & ":O" & Target.Row).Copy Worksheets("Handover").Range("E" & NR)
      ' Rows(Target.Row).Delete
      End Select
  .EnableEvents = True
  .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: splendid!

both codes work perfectly, thank you very much Myles